# how to combine the merge columns (below header) into one as header?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question. Just wondering how do I merge these columns of 3 into one as a header with python from a csv file? such that the column can be February 2022 Percent, February 2022 Planning amount etc. (highlighted in the image)

[image]

In python jupyter, the data looks like this

[image]

raw table :

```
Production number   Raw Materials   Materials Leadtime   Month DESC January         February            March           April           May         June            Total       
            Month YEAR  2022            2022            2022            2022            2022            2022                    
            Already purchased   Percent     Planning amount To consume amount   Percent     Planning amount To consume amount   Percent     Planning amount To consume amount   Percent     Planning amount To consume amount   Percent     Planning amount To consume amount   Percent     Planning amount To consume amount   Percent     Consume amount  Planned amount 
7474949 paper   5   AEC 0.5 3,890   2,899   0.5 3,890   2,899   0.5 3,890   2,899   0.5 3,890   2,899   0.5 3,890   2,899   0.5 3,890   2,899   0.5 2,899   3,890
7474950 cotton  4   DFH 0.6 5,990   3,899   0.6 5,990   3,899   0.6 5,990   3,899   0.6 5,990   3,899   0.6 5,990   3,899   0.6 5,990   3,899   0.6 3,899   5,990
7474951 cotton  6   HJL 0.1 6,779   8,890   0.1 6,779   8,890   0.1 6,779   8,890   0.1 6,779   8,890   0.1 6,779   8,890   0.1 6,779   8,890   0.1 8,890   6,779
7474952 cotton  8   DFH 0.3 2,550   5,488   0.3 2,550   5,488   0.3 2,550   5,488   0.3 2,550   5,488   0.3 2,550   5,488   0.3 2,550   5,488   0.3 5,488   2,550
7474953 cotton  4   DFH 0.4 5,773   3,999   0.4 5,773   3,999   0.4 5,773   3,999   0.4 5,773   3,999   0.4 5,773   3,999   0.4 5,773   3,999   0.4 3,999   5,773
7474954 cotton  6   HJL 0.5 4,989   5,999   0.5 4,989   5,999   0.5 4,989   5,999   0.5 4,989   5,999   0.5 4,989   5,999   0.5 4,989   5,999   0.5 5,999   4,989
7474955 wool    5   AEC 0.6 6,448   2,900   0.6 6,448   2,900   0.6 6,448   2,900   0.6 6,448   2,900   0.6 6,448   2,900   0.6 6,448   2,900   0.6 2,900   6,448
```

(can copy into excel to see the format then save as csv to import in python)

link for the table: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A7gyiRX85HJazB0zenCm6G5jSpN6F6Gc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you share the data in raw format

Comment: how should I post the raw format?

Comment: Post it in question itself, in the form of text so that we can directly read the values into a datframe, a dictionary or list should do

Comment: I try to paste it in form of text, but then it only allows pic as a table, so i am not sure

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar should be ok now

Comment: its better if you can directly share ur csv/xlsx file. uload on drive and share link

Comment: how shall I share the csv file upload?

Comment: upload on google drive and share link

Answer (score 0):

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(['Column1', 'Column2', 'Value1', 'Value2'], columns=['Column0'])
df_test['Column01'] = ['Column11', None, 'Value11', 'Value21']

final_cols = []
for current_column in df_test.columns:
  final_col_name = current_column
  
  if df_test[current_column][0] is not None:
    final_col_name = final_col_name + '_' + df_test[current_column][0]
    
  if df_test[current_column][1] is not None:
    final_col_name = final_col_name + '_' + df_test[current_column][1]
    
  final_cols.append(final_col_name)
df_test.columns = final_cols
df_test = df_test.iloc[2:].reset_index(drop=True)

df_test
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).